Horror movie with demons spawned from a blood pit
Ok I remember watching this movie when I lived in Hong Kong circa 1996-1997. I remember seeing it on HBO or some movie channel like that.
The only scenes I remember were three demons being summoned from some pit in a cave by a girl and when they spawned they were covered in blood. I also remember some scene with a gardener and something to do with his teeth being pulled out?
It was in American English. I saw it around 1996-1997 and it seems like it was from that time period. Not a high budget movie. I feel like it could have been a tales from the crypt keeper story but I dont remember seeing any of that. It had that vibe to it though. Because of the subject matter i put it in Horror but it could have been comedy too.

Was the movie American\in English? Was it from the 90s? Was it a horror movie?

The movie is most likely Sometimes They Come Back... Again (1996).
It stars Michael Gross of Family Ties fame, Robert Arquette (aka Alexis Arquette), and Hilary Swank.  While this is a sequel to the 1991 movie Sometimes They Come Back, it is more of a retelling of the first movie, adapted from the Stephen King short story of the same name.  The antagonists return from the grave as Demons by rising from a pool of blood.  After some ridiculous jerking and shaking they take on human form to exact revenge on Michael Gross' character and family.

Just saw this comment. Thats It!!!!!!
